# Sysbench MySQL cannot connect

Tags: mysql, benchmark

I have created a user named sbtest, with no password, with all rights on sbtest, and the following error occurs. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ sysbench --test=oltp run --debug
sysbench 0.4.12:  multi-threaded system evaluation benchmark

No DB drivers specified, using mysql
DEBUG: mysql_init(0xc854f0)
DEBUG: mysql_real_connect(0xc854f0, "localhost", "sbtest", "(null)", "sbtest", 3306, "(null)", CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS)
DEBUG: mysql_real_query(0xc854f0, "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'sbtest'", 31) = 0
DEBUG: mysql_store_result(0xc854f0) = 0xc9dce0
DEBUG: mysql_num_fields(0xc9dce0) = 18
DEBUG: mysql_fetch_fields(0xc9dce0) = 0xc9fce0
DEBUG: mysql_fetch_row(0xc9dce0) = (nil)
ALERT: Error: failed to determine table 'sbtest' type!
ALERT: MySQL error: 
DEBUG: mysql_free_result(0xc9dce0)
DEBUG: mysql_close(0xc854f0)
FATAL: failed to get database capabilities
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run "prepare" first. It will create the table required for the benchmark.

In your case, it should be

`sysbench --test=oltp prepare`

Comment: You are right, but I also need to create user sbtest that has privlleges on database sbtest, however these can be configruable.

Answer (score 3):

#### Create `sbtest` database and `sbtest` user.

If you're not going to supply command parameters to the `sysbench` command then you'll need to create the database and user that it expects when talking with the MySQL server.

**Log in to your MySQL server using the `root` user or whatever you like:**

```
mysql -u root -p
```

**Create `sbtest` database, `sbtest` user and grant privileges:**

```
CREATE DATABASE sbtest;
CREATE USER 'sbtest'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'sbtest'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit;
```

**Prepare database:**

```
sysbench --test=oltp --db-driver=mysql prepare
```